# Jquery overlay from checking php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this script from JQuery.

```
<script> 

// create custom animation algorithm for jQuery called "drop" 
$.easing.drop = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
};


// loading animation
$.tools.overlay.addEffect("drop", function(css, done) { 

   // use Overlay API to gain access to crucial elements
   var conf = this.getConf(),
       overlay = this.getOverlay();           

   // determine initial position for the overlay
   if (conf.fixed)  {
      css.position = 'fixed';
   } else {
      css.top += $(window).scrollTop();
      css.left += $(window).scrollLeft();
      css.position = 'absolute';
   } 

   // position the overlay and show it
   overlay.css(css).show();

   // begin animating with our custom easing
   overlay.animate({ top: '+=55',  opacity: 1,  width: '+=20'}, 400, 'drop', done);

   /* closing animation */
   }, function(done) {
      this.getOverlay().animate({top:'-=55', opacity:0, width:'-=20'}, 300, 'drop', function() {
         $(this).hide();
         done.call();      
      });
   }
);

$("img[rel]").overlay({
    effect: 'drop',
    mask: '#789'
});
</script>
```

Right now it works by me clicking on an image.  Then the overlay comes up with whatever is in the div.  However I want to take out clicking the image and just have the overlay come up with an if statement in PHP. any ideas...im not very good at js.

EDIT:

yes im using the JQuery plugin Easing.  However the overlay works great...and the overlay works by clicking on an image with the rel attribute like this

```
<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3651/3445879840_7ca4b491e9_m.jpg" rel="#mies1"/>
```

However I don't want to click on the images I want it to come up automatically.

Comment: I suppose you're using some jQuery plugin that provides the actual `.overlay` method?

Comment: If this is for debugging purposes then maybe you'd be better off using XDebug and/or FirePHP for this?

Comment: yes im using the JQuery plugin Easing.  However the overlay works great...and the overlay works by clicking on an img with the rel attribute like this 
<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3651/3445879840_7ca4b491e9_m.jpg" rel="#mies1"/> 
However I don't want to click on the images I want it to come up automatically.

Comment: Could you not just simulate the `.click()` event for simplicity, by calling that function on the image you desire?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($whatever) { ?>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
         $("img[rel]").click();
    }); 
<?php } ?>
```